# Rails PG::Error: ERROR: value "214524245325432453" is out of range for type integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql

This error is is triggered by PG before any validations like "greater_than". How can I handle this the Rails way and not in the controller?

Comment: You get the PG exception even if you have a max size validation on the model?

Comment: Validations occur before db access. You'll need to provide more context.

Comment: I think you'll need to show your Rails model, the Postgresql table generated from it, and the query that gives the error (obtained from the PostgreSQL logs)

Comment: Also, if you actually want to store (or check for) values larger than maxint, use a `bigint`.

Comment: I provide some greater_than validations, but it simply don't work.. For some reason this error is triggered before validations. So I use(now) bigint... until I find a solution